# What’s the term for “hearing” words when you read or think?

Tags: single-word-requests

If you’re anything like me, you may hear a little voice in your head when you read (e.g., this post) or think to yourself. **THAT VOICE MAY GET LOUDER ON CUE**, <sub>*or it may get softer on cue*</sub>.

At any rate, is there a word for this?

I ask, because I am writing an essay on how the language of set theory has facilitated mathematics in probability theory.  One of my sections is on the vocabulary that the former has contributed to the latter, and I would like to point out that having specific words to describe concepts not only provides us with an efficient medium for discussion, but it can also concrete our thought processes.

---

As @HotLicks said in the comments, I am asking (more or less) if there exists an auditory analogue of *visualize*.

I just remembered from my psychology class that a scientist might call this an *auditory memory* being *rehearsed* in the *working* section of one’s short-term memory.

Comment: I'm tempted to say "What do the voices in your head suggest?", but I agree that there's no obvious analog to "visualize".

Comment: @HotLicks What do you mean by the first part?

Comment: It's what I call "The Mind's Ear", and it is part of the reading equipment of many fluent English readers and writers, particularly poets. It routes written material through speech processing routines, producing an aural image of the language chunk. It's involved in lots of English grammar rules, like _a/an_, because they are all based on the sound of the language. This is a hard thing for a non-native speaker to pick up without constant reinforcement from native speakers because English spelling is so awful, but fluent native readers take it for granted.

Comment: The "first part" is based on an old line of jokes -- folks telling their doctors that they "hear voices".  Supposedly a symptom of certain psychological disorders.  When John Glen was being debriefed after the first US orbital space flight, he described specks floating outside his cabin window.  He said they looked like fireflies.  A shrink then asked "What did they say, John?"

Comment: There is a word for imagining a voice enunciating the words of a book as you read them — subvocalization. Of course one might merely *think* about hearing the words without any auditory experience, or he or she may manage to actually have a genuine auditory experience.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's called **subvocalization**:

> Subvocalization (also known as auditory reassurance) is a very common habit among readers. It involves saying words in your head while reading and it’s one of the main reasons why people read slowly and have trouble improving their reading speed.
>   <sub>[Speed Reading Tips: 5 Ways to Minimize Subvocalization](https://www.irisreading.com/speed-reading-tips-5-ways-to-minimize-subvocalization/)</sub>

Comment: Wait, there's people that DON'T do this?? How do you read something without hearing it in your head?

Comment: I also do this, and I read quite fast...

Comment: @MCMastery That's tricky to describe. It's like... getting directly from the written word to its meaning, without the "hearing it" step? Much like thinking about something without "inner-describing it", I guess.

Comment: I feel like I can "turn it off", so to speak. When I'm glancing the page looking for what I need I don't subvocalize anything, only when I find what I want to actually read does it start.

Comment: @MCMastery: Try going to https://www.spreeder.com/app.php, use the default text and set it to 800 wpm. You'll be able to recognize most of the words displayed, probably get the gist of what is being said, but you'll only be able to subvocalize a fraction of them, if any.

Comment: @MCMastery: It's kind of amazing what the mind can do. In one speed reading exercise I've tried, a sequence of digits was displayed for a fraction of a second And I would have to repeat them. At the higher levels the display was so brief that I had no conscious memory of seeing the digits at all. But often I would be able to write down what they were, as if by a "sixth sense".

Comment: @MCMastery - When I read its as if I'm watching a movie play out. Sometimes I'm one of the characters, sometimes not. When I WRITE I hear the words though.

Comment: Also, I don't think sub-vocalize is the right word. Supposedly it means:
"Utter (words or sounds) with the lips silently or with barely audible sound, especially when talking to oneself, memorizing something, or reading." This implies actually muttering silently to oneself, not just "hearing" words in your head.

Answer (score 8):

Subvocalization is an excellent answer *if you don't Actually Hear* the words.  If you DO hear the words, or perhaps feel them or smell them, the 'overlapping' of normal sensory input into non-ordinary perception (i.e. colors that have numeric value, etc) it's known as [Synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia), and is far more common than those of us with it care to admit.

Comment: Excellent distinction! I forgot to point this out. In this post, I more meant that the subject is not experiencing sensations unfounded in reality.

Comment: I thought synesthesia is perception is of a completely different type than typically associated with the stimulus (e.g. you hear or read a number, and perceive a color). If you hear the same word that you're reading, is that really considered synesthesia?

Comment: @Barmar: according to my psychologist, yes.  It's a poorly understood largely undiscovered 'spectrum' type disorder, no two cases are exactly the same.  In this case, merely 'seeing' the word, as opposed to 'reading' it is sufficient.  If you have additional or other information I'd love to hear it  !  :) (pun intended)

Comment: I glanced at the wikipedia article you linked to, and didn't notice anything like this, but I admit I didn't read it thoroughly. Can you  copy specific quotes from the article that support your case?