# What's the term for "seeing" words when you hear spoken language?

Tags: single-word-requests

[Some people "hear" a spoken voice in their head when they read words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410539/what-s-the-term-for-hearing-words-when-you-read-or-think), apparently called *subvocalization*.

What do you call it when you hear someone speaking and your brain turns it into actual words that you "see" before you in your mind's eye?  This happens without any particular effort or intention.

Comment: Not the point of the question, but is either of these not normal / something an average person does?

Comment: @AthomSfere, if this is actually a form of synesthesia, it's probably not common at all.

Comment: Following @barbecue’s link, I see synesthesia is described as visual effects integrated into your visual perception, *really* seeing it.  You wrote “mind’s eye” which is not the same thing.  I interpret your description to mean that the glyphs are called up in an internal space, separate from the picture you get from your eyes.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @JDługosz, synesthesia can be either directly perceived or in the mind's eye depending on the particular person.

Answer (score 9):

If this happens without conscious effort, then it may be a form of [synesthesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia) usually called [ticker tape synesthesia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24223561).

Comment: Reading the abstract to that document you linked to, I'd have to say that's it.

Comment: A quick search for ticker tape synesthesia will return lots of discussions on various forums of this phenomenon, reddit, etc, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of actual research.

Comment: Hmm, so subvocalization is “normal” (common anyway; those are the people who mix up homonyms) in adults,so it doesn't need a term?  But the other way around is a medical condition?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing words as images is called Visualization.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is not enough on Stack Exchange to state an answer; a good answer should *explain* the reasoning, including references and examples as may be appropriate. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.